# Is fluid design as important as responsive design?

Tags: responsive-design, fluid

I am a relatively new web developer.

My site will be mostly text heavy (book reviews). As a way to challenge myself, I am trying to build a mobile first fluid, responsive site even though my site would probably be best suited to desktops.

I have noticed both fluid and responsive sites. Some are one or the other, and occasionally both.

I have been a bit frustrated with coding a fluid responsive site from scratch. However, fluid responsive looks cooler than responsive when done correctly. Responsive only sites seem to "snap" into place at the breakpoints of their media queries, but look stiff and less professional compared to fluid responsive sites whenever the viewpoint is resized.

However, I do not anticipate mobile and tablet users resizing their viewports often because they do not have much screen space. It seems more important that all elements are positioned on the page efficiently upon loading depending upon viewport size. Fluid seems to be most important on large screen desktops where resizing the viewport will be fairly common.

All of that said, is fluidity really important, or should I focus on responsive design at fixed breakpoints even though it does not look as nice?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks to me like  a question for the user experience stackexchange site. http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, fluid is always better because it's impossible to foresee what devices users will use, and will use in three years. If it's important depends on what you find important for your site - if it takes too long to figure out how to do it nicely and only a few users will get a uglier (but working!) design, it may be alright.